# How do I change the hostname in a fhgfs management node?

Tags: linux, storage

[`FHGFS`](http://www.fhgfs.com/cms/) is a high performance parallel file system typically used in clusters.

How would you go about changing the hostname of the management server without breaking connection between the storage and meta servers?

Answer (score 0):

see here: http://www.fhgfs.com/wiki/FAQ#hostname_changed
basically, you just have to define static IDs via the nodeID file.

Comment: Please include the relevant information here to prevent link rot and to make this site more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `mgmtd` hostname is easy. Just make sure, that all storage and meta nodes use correct hostname (or even better an IP address) defined in `/etc/fhgfs/fhgfs-meta.conf` or `/etc/fhgfs/fhgfs-storage.conf`:

```
sysMgmtdHost                 = 192.168.1.1
```

`mgmtd` node store all data in a directory defined in `/etc/fhgfs/fhgfs-mgmtd.conf`, e.g.:

```
storeMgmtdDirectory            = /srv/fhgfs/mgmtd
```

Then `/srv/fhgfs/mgmtd/originalNodeID` contains original hostname, there's no need to change that, just make sure that:

```
$ fhgfs-check-servers
```

succeeds (ideally test it from all servers).